# How to prevent sidebar from scrolling flexdashboard inputs? R and Rmarkdwown

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have this dashboard I am building with Flexdashboard. But I cannot figure out how to remove the scroll bar. I'm using html breaks 
 to create that space but if there is a better way please let me know.

Here is an image of what I see in my browser.

[image]

I would like to have the bottom R image be as close to the bottom as possible but more importantly than that I cannot have the scroll bar there.

This is some code I have tried but it didn't work.

````
---
title: "Sample"
date: "7/23/2021"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

<style>
 .sidebar { 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
</style>


Inputs {.sidebar data-width=400}
=====================================


$$\\[.01in]$$


```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}

knitr::include_graphics("https://workingnation.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/R_logo.svg_.png")
```




Long Text Here-000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}

knitr::include_graphics("https://workingnation.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/R_logo.svg_.png")
```

# Page 1

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A


Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B


### Chart C
````